# What will be the maximum heap size when we set only minimum heap size using -Xms in java?

Tags: java

By default in my machine taking 10 gb of maximum heap size because we have 40 gb memory. When i set -Xms15g, what will be the maximum heap size ?

Comment: Title doesn't match question body; **exactly** what arguments are set?

Comment: -Xms<size> - Set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size> - Set maximum Java heap size

Comment: By default in my machine taking 10 gb of maximum heap size because we have 40 gb memory. When i set -Xms15g, what will be the maximum heap size ?